# How to show that every continuous function from $[0:1]$ to $[0:1]$ has a fixed point?

Tags: general-topology

This exercise is from Munkres topology:

Let $f:[0:1]\rightarrow [0:1]$ be a continuous function. How can we prove that there exists some point $x\in [0:1]$ such that, $f(x)=x$?

Any ideas please?

Comment: Well, if it's continuous then it has to intersect the line $y=x$, doesn't it?

Comment: All these function has to cross the line $x=y$.

Comment: @Surb: Beat you by 6 seconds :)

Comment: Intermediate theorem on $f(x)-x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Consider the function $h\colon x\mapsto f(x)-x$ and use the intermediate theorem.

Notice that
$$h(0)h(1)\le0$$

Comment: Why is it true that $h(0)h(1)\le 0$?

Comment: Don't forget that the range of $f$ is the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: I know so , $h(0)h(1)\le 1$ not necessarly $0$. it may happen that $h(1)=0.5$ and $h(0)=0.5$ so the equation is not true!

Comment: No we have $h(1)=f(1)-1\le0$. So $h(1)$ is non positive.

Comment: right. Now the required follows directly :) thanx

Comment: You're welcome:)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Consider a square, then every continuous curve going from one edge to the opposite one has to cross the diagonal of the square.